# Javscaript Make image appear when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I working on displaying information when we press a radio button. I wanted to display an image in addition to this, so I did the following, but the text appears well, but the image is not displayed. What should I do?

[image]

The image will look like this:

[image]

my project path

```
html

<form name="image_type">
    <input type="radio" name="check_img" value="눈" onclick="eyesinfo()" /><span>눈</span
</form>
<p class="disease-information"></p>

<script>
    function eyesinfo(){
        var info = "sometext<br><img src='images\earsexample.jpg'>";
        $('.disease-information').html(info);

}
</script>
```

Comment: what is the path that in img src?

Comment: Looks like you are not providing correct image path in `src`. Please show us where you have stored images ?

Comment: image path is hi/images/earsexample.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Please use below code it will work for you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="image_type">
    <input type="radio" name="check_img" value="눈" onclick="eyesinfo()" /><span>눈</span>
</form>
<p class="disease-information"></p>

<script>
    function eyesinfo(){
        var info = "sometext<br><img src='https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png'>";
        $('.disease-information').html(info);

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: google img is work ,but my local img is dosen't work :(

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to add a real image path for the attribute of img.

```
var info = "sometext<br><img src='https://freeiconshop.com/wp-content/uploads/edd/eye-outline.png'>";
$('.disease-information').html(info);
```

Comment: it works, but my local imges doesn't work. I think my path is wrong, but i don't know what is wrong

Answer (score 1):

Please change your script as follows:

```
<script>
  function eyesinfo(){
    let img = document.createElement("img");
    $(img).attr("src","https://petokala.com/images/logo.png");
    $(".disease-information").html('');
    $(img).appendTo($('.disease-information'));
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for comment! The result of some tests is that my path is wrong.

Comment: your welcome. It makes me happy that your problem solved.